# Why does moving an electrostatically charged object near a compass only attract it temporarily?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I've noticed that if I rub a plastic spoon with some fabric for ~20 seconds and hold it near a compass, it will attract its nearest pole. However, if I keep the spoon stationary, the needle will drift back to its old orientation after several seconds, seemingly no longer affected by the electrostatic charge.

Further, when I move the object away, the needle will suddenly jump back to where the object had been, and stay *there* for several seconds before drifting back to its original orientation.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 4):

1. A compass has magnet to detect a magnetic field.
2. It will not interact with electrostatic force, which is the only force interacting when the spoon is kept  stationary.
3. However, moving the spoon produces magnetic field of its own via Ampere's law.
4. Another way to see this via lorentz force, where force acts only on a moving charge in the presence of magnetic field.

Comment: #2 seems a bit strong.  I agree it is not designed to interact with them, but it might be possible to induce charges on the needle that are affected by static charges.

Comment: If #2 is true, then why does the needle stay attracted to the spoon for several seconds even when stationary?

Comment: As mentioned by @BowlOfRed, it could be because of some induced charges on the metallic needle of the compass.

Comment: Can you explain how this fits into the rest of the phenomenon I explained (especially re: the attraction only being temporary)?

Comment: I am not really sure why attraction because of induction is only temporary here.

Comment: "why does the needle stay attracted to the spoon for several seconds even when stationary?" maybe it is due to mechanical resistance of the needle. Try it with a magnet, bring close, take it fast away and see if the needle sticks for a while.

Comment: @annav I tried but could not reproduce the effect with a magnet, even trying to get it stuck.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this with another compass, nor with a freestanding magnet on a low-friction surface. Something must be going on with this specific compass.

Comment: what about the spoon. If it is iron and standing in the same place for a long time it acquires a magnetization from the  magnetic field of the earth. This is easy to see in old metal  heaters of this type https://www.energy.gov/energysaver/home-heating-systems/heat-distribution-systems

Comment: @annav the spoon is plastic.

Answer (score 0):

Your experiment may be affected by something not included in your model, as pointed out by @BowlOfRed. Here are some details:

If there are loose charges present in equilibrium on the surface of the compass needle, then bringing a charged object near the needle will redistribute those mobile charges and in so doing, the needle will get *polarized* and then rotate so it is pointing towards the charged object.

Charges caused by rubbing dissimilar materials together will dissipate fairly quickly if the air surrounding them is moist, which would make this effect die out, and allow the compass needle to realign itself with the earth's magnetic field.

Because the forces involved here are small, the experiment needs to be carefully designed to not get messed up by small but unanticipated effects.